# How to completely remove Anaconda3 from Windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda

I screwed up and installed Anaconda 2.7 instead of 3.5 in Windows. I thought 'no biggie, Ill just have both' and then installed 3.5 as well. This caused some problems trying to keep track of whats what as far as packages and modules go, so I said 'to hell with this, let's uninstall and start over.' So I tried that.

I tried to follow the instructions [here](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install), but I do not understand the instructions. It says:

> On all systems, remove configuration files and directories from Anaconda and its programs by opening a terminal window (on Windows:
>   Start - Command Prompt) and installing the conda package:
>
> ```
> conda install anaconda-clean
> ```
>
> Next, in the same window, run Anaconda-Clean with one of these three options:
>
> Remove all Anaconda-related files and directories with a prompt to answer “yes” before deleting each one (type `clean`)
>
> Remove all Anaconda-related files and directories without being prompted to delete each one (type `clean –yes`)
>
> Remove all Anaconda-related files and directories and create a backup copy of the file/directory in a .anaconda_backup folder in your home directory (type `clean –backup`)

WTF is `run Anaconda-Clean`? I tried typing `Anaconda-Clean -clean` in the command line, but got this:

[image]

Whatever, I rolled on and tried to uninstall through Add/Remove. I ran it on both Anaconda 2 install and the Anaconda 3 install, but Anaconda3 was still in my start menu. Also, there is some other Python 2.7.11 thing in my Add/Remove Programs menu which will not uninstall.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337928/how-to-remove-anaconda-from-windows-completely), which says there should be an uninstaller in Anaconda3. There is not. It also suggested I reinstall 3, and then uninstall again. I tried that. It still won't be completely uninstalled.

Is there a brute force way to completely remove all things Anaconda and python from this PC?!?! (This should not be that hard...)

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/53272056/7735095 offers a detailed description how to use `anaconda-clean`

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to use "anaconda-clean". (Instead of "anaconda-clean clean".)

It looks like the raw_input() problem is a Python 2 versus Python 3 problem. It might work to create a new Python 2 environment with "conda create -n p2 python=2", activate it with "activate p2", and run "anaconda-clean" there.

If you want to use a brute force way instead, check your home directory for any configuration files or directories and delete them, and remove any desktop icons or start menu items.