# anaconda3 4.4 (64bit) re-install error

Tags: anaconda

I installed Anaconda3 4.4 on my win10 laptop and everything went well. When I started spider the Kernel wouldn't start. and my anti virus (AVG) popped up to block something related to the program. I shut spider and anaconda navigator down and tried to reopened them, however the icon to start anaconda was removed i looked in the folder as well and could not find an exe file for it either. so i tried to uninstall. i ran the anaconda uninstall feature provided by Continuum and then tried to reinstall the program. and i get an error message "Failed to create Anaconda Menus" I'm not sure what to do from here

I did go in to AVG and delete the quarantined file from it. and i went through the registry as stated here [How to remove anaconda from windows completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337928/how-to-remove-anaconda-from-windows-completely?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

On the Start menu, enter "Control Panel" in the search box and select Control Panel from the results. Under "Programs" you should see "Uninstall a Program". You should find Anaconda.

Comment: It may be listed under "P" for Python, instead of "A" for Anaconda. YMMV