# How to uninstall (mini)conda entirely on Windows

Tags: python, windows, conda, uninstallation, miniconda

I was surprised to be unable to find any information anywhere on the web on how to do this properly, but I suppose my surprise ought to be mitigated by the fact that normally this can be done via Microsoft's 'Add or Remove Programs' via the Control Panel.

This option is not available to me at this time, since I had installed Python again elsewhere (without having uninstalled it), then uninstalled *that* installation the standard way. Now, despite no option for uninstalling conda via the Control Panel, conda persists in my command line.

Now, the goal is to remove every trace of it, to end up in a state as though conda never existed on my machine in the first place before I reinstall it to the necessary location.

I have a bad feeling that if I simply delete the files and then reinstall, this will cause problems. Does anyone have any guidance in how to achieve the above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Anaconda from Windows completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337928/how-to-remove-anaconda-from-windows-completely)

Comment: Thanks, Melvin. As said there, 'Uninstall-Anaconda.exe' does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 18):

Open the folder where you installed miniconda, and then search for uninstall.exe. Open that it will erase miniconda for you.

Answer (score 2):

Initially also me I didn't found the program but I discover next that in windows is a bit hidden with the name of Python 3.x.x(Miniconda# x.x.x 64-bit).[Here the image for an example how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8bkq.jpg)
In the case of it isn't listed in the control panel use this linux method deleting also the hidden files: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html.