# The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully

Tags: anaconda, conda

I tried to update or install new packages from anaconda and lately, this message has appeared:

```
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following package are causing the inconsistency:

   - defaults/win-32::anaconda==5.3.1=py37_0

done
```

I tried with `conda clean --all` and then `conda update --all` but it persists.

**Conda Info**

```
active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\NAME\Continuum
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\NAME\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\NAME\.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.11
    conda-build version : 3.17.7
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       base environment : C:\Users\NAME\Continuum  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-32
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-32
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-32
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-32
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\NAME\Continuum\pkgs
                          C:\Users\NAME\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\NAME\Continuum\envs
                          C:\Users\NAME\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-32
             user-agent : conda/4.6.11 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: did anyone get any progress on this, if I have to manually update 100 issues it will take me forever.  i cant even uninstall anaconda and start over, due to the same issue :(

Comment: for those who decide to uninstall-reinstall: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/macos.html#install-macos-silent
I was in the situation that every command involving ```conda``` failed due to environment inconsistency. Highly recommend to uninstall-reinstall anaconda entirely

Answer (score 150, accepted):

I had faced the same problem. Simply running

```
conda install anaconda
```

solved the problem for me.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I did as you suggested. But I'm still getting inconsistencies. I'm running osx-64, do you run osx also?

Comment: Yes, I have macOS Mojave v10.14.4.

Comment: I get the error with `conda update --all`, so it doesn't solve the problem (on some cases), but `conda install` seems to work (and to update other packages in the list)

Comment: For me the solution was in 2 steps: first, `conda install anaconda` which just installed anaconda package and removed one conda package + updated a few dependencies. Then I followed it with `conda update --all` and everything was fine again! My system is Ubuntu 18.04 and I ran into this problem after updating `spyder` package which also caused an update to `conda` itself, and this caused the inconsistency.

Comment: `conda install anaconda` worked for me too, although I had to wait more than 5 minutes for conda to propose a package plan.

Comment: When I did `conda install anaconda` it decided to upgrade 153 packages, install an additional 151 and downgrade 2.  5 mins later and it's still going.  I'm in my base environment.

Comment: 20 minutes later and the spinning `/ - | \\` is still going >:(

Comment: @JasonS did it ever complete? I am in the same situation currently

Comment: I gave up, restarted with Miniconda3-4.7.12+mamba. (requires Python 3 at least for base environment; this is the last miniconda installer with BSD3 licensing)

Comment: Try `conda update conda` first before `conda update anaconda`. The former might solve your problems with minimal needs for installs/upgrades/downgrades and just updates the [ana,mini]conda system and its dependency needs itself, rather than the entirety of anaconda3. Also, running the former first, may make the latter work more efficiently if you decide to do that as well.

Comment: why or how does installing `conda install anaconda` fix the issue? does installing `anaconda` trigger some fix all inconsistencies? or does it trigger an `conda update --all`?

Comment: conda update conda was sufficient to resolve conflicts in my case

Comment: In my case, I had to run `conda install anaconda` *two* times in a row. The first one took several long minutes, and conda downgraded and removed a number of packages, but I still got the warnings. So I ran `conda install anaconda` a second time. This time it upgraded anaconda itself and a number of other packages. I finished with `conda update --all`, and now my environment is consistent.

Comment: For those using `miniconda` if you don't want to install `anaconda` see @Jack Kelly' answer. (activate the environment causing problem, then `conda install conda --force-reinstall` twice (yes twice), then `conda update --all`), and don't forget to add +1 to @Jack Kelly' answer if it helped ;-).

Comment: Doing ```conda update -all``` a bunch of times mixed with ```conda install [any of the offending packages]``` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 78):

saw this on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/AnQWEGUcDOs)

> This message was added in conda 4.6.9, previously there was no indication when conda detected an inconsistent environment unless conda was run in debug mode.  It is likely that your environment was inconsistent for some time but the upgrade to conda made it visible.  The best option it to run "conda install package_name" for the inconsistent packages to let conda try to restore consistency.

and it really works for me.

Maybe you should try `conda install anaconda` in your situation.

Comment: The inconsistent environment was a nagging issue for ALL of my conda environments, `conda install anaconda` didn't cut it. I need to do exactly this: (re)install each package it called out individually. Thanks!

Comment: @conner.xyz  I found myself in a similar situation, and decided that writing a snippet that reinstalled each package was a fair way to go (see my answer below). Was lucky enough to not have to work through multiple environments, however.

Comment: Great answer - really nice to have an explanation of why this has happened as well as a succinct fix that (at least for me) works perfectly.

Answer (score 54):

The inconsistencies are caused due to different versions of the packages, and their clashing dependencies.

```
conda update --all
```

This command updates all the packages, and then conda solves the inconsistency on its own.

Comment: This is the better answer, because it only updates packages that conflict and caused the inconsistencies.

Comment: This does NOT solve the problem because the inconsistency is not caused by dependencies, but rather by [change in metadata](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8490#issuecomment-481849564) on the server side (i.e. in channel). I tried this and it didn't work, however as the link says, it's a warning that can be ignored.

Comment: While "conda upgrade conda" fails, "conda install anaconda; conda update --all" solved my problem.

Comment: ```conda update --all``` just tells me about the package conflicts without attempting to solve them.

Answer (score 28):

Had this same problem and none of the other solutions worked for me. Ended up having to uninstall and reinstall conda, then reinstall all of my libraries.

Comment: Why the downvote? I tried many of the other solutions, which all resulted in the same message about inconsistent packages and conda spinning forever. A full reinstall took just a few minutes and gave me a working system again. I obviously wouldn't recommend this if you have any valuable environments that need to be preserved.

Comment: @BasSwinckels lol maybe I didn't emphasize enough that NONE of the other solutions worked for me.

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me... I'm already on my third installation of anaconda... I'm never going to update it again.

Answer (score 25):

I was getting an `environment is inconsistent` error when I tried to update my `base` conda environment. I'm using miniconda. Unfortunately, none of the answers above worked for me.

What did work for me was:

```sh
conda activate base
conda install conda --force-reinstall
conda install conda --force-reinstall
conda update --all
```

(Yes, for some reason it was necessary to run `conda install conda --force-reinstall` twice!)

Comment: I had `miniconda` and didn't want to install `anaconda` (as in the accepted answer) and this worked perfectly. And yes it was necessary to run `conda install conda --force-reinstall` twice! Just in case: change the name of your environment appropriately (`conda activate [environemtn_name]`). Thanks @Jack Kelly.

Comment: I've installed Anaconda on my Mac. I needed pandoc. Could not find it in Anaconda navigator, so I tried conda. Got the same error as the OP. Tried this solution, and it fixed the error. I was able to install pandoc afterwards.

Comment: still having inconsistency in force-reinstall. how long have you waited for that?

Comment: I was stuck in a loop whereby if I tried to remove the packages listed as the cause of the inconsistency I couldn't because of the inconsistency!
`defaults/osx-64::conda==23.3.1=py38hecd8cb5_0` `conda-forge/osx-64::conda-build==3.21.8=py38h50d1736_0` `defaults/osx-64::anaconda-navigator==2.1.4=py38hecd8cb5_0` `defaults/osx-64::thinc==8.0.15=py38hc29d2bd_0` `defaults/noarch::conda-token==0.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0` For these packages, the solution presented here worked.

Comment: When I entered the 4th day of running the first force-reinstall and was still at 25%, I gave up and reinstalled Anaconda from scratch. Not only I had to resume working, but also Windows required a restart for updates.

Answer (score 22):

Ultimate solutions:

```
conda activate base
conda install anaconda
conda update --all
```

Works on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 (credits to @MF.OX for ubuntu).

Removed following problems for me:

- `The environment is inconsistent`
- `WARNING conda.base.context:use_only_tar_bz2(632)`

Comment: thanks, it works.  After base env update,
I have activated my virtual env, and repeated ```conda upadte --all``` to get ```# All requested packages alread installed.``` message.

Comment: Eventually worked, had to wait 15 mins of spinning for the install anaconda to resolve the problems.

Answer (score 15):

If the other solutions don't work, reverting the environment can fix this.

Use `conda list --revisions`, pick a revision number, and use `conda install --revision [#]`  going back step-by-step until everything works again.

Answer (score 12):

Given a situation like the following,

```
> conda update -c intel --all
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: |
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - intel/win-64::ipython==6.3.1=py36_3
  - intel/win-64::prompt_toolkit==1.0.15=py36_2
done
```

As mentioned in other answers, the idea is to have some sort of re-`install`ation to occur for the inconsistent packages.

Thus, with a few copy-&-paste's, you could:

```
> conda install intel/win-64::ipython==6.3.1=py36_3
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: /
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - intel/win-64::ipython==6.3.1=py36_3
  - intel/win-64::prompt_toolkit==1.0.15=py36_2
done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: c:\conda

  added / updated specs:
    - ipython


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  jedi               intel/win-64::jedi-0.12.0-py36_2
  parso              intel/win-64::parso-0.2.0-py36_2
  pygments           intel/win-64::pygments-2.2.0-py36_5
  wcwidth            intel/win-64::wcwidth-0.1.7-py36_6


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

*(and you would have to repeat for all the packages)*

---

### My “Shortcut”

Alternatively, cook up an (ugly) one-liner (this should work for Windows as well as other platforms)

> *Note*: by "ORIGINAL_COMMAND", I'm referring to any command that gives you the error message (without any other side-effects, ideally)

```
<ORIGINAL_COMMAND> 2>&1 | python -c "import sys,re,conda.cli; conda.cli.main('conda','install','-y',*re.findall(r'^\s*-\s*(\S+)$',sys.stdin.read(),re.MULTILINE))"
```

Expanding the above one-liner:

```py
from re import findall, MULTILINE
from sys import stdin
from conda.cli import main

main(
    "conda", "install", "-y",
    "--force",  # Maybe add a '--force'/'--force-reinstall' (I didn't add it for the one-liner above)
    *findall(r"^\s*-\s*(\S+)$", stdin.read(), MULTILINE)  # Here are the offenders
)
```

Answer (score 8):

The command `conda install -c anaconda anaconda` did the trick for me. For my setup, I need to specify the channel otherwise it would not work. After running the command in the terminal, I was prompted to update a list of packages that was found to be inconsistent. Without this step, I was not able to install or update any packages with `conda install <package_name>` or `conda update <package_name` respectively.

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was to

```
`conda remove <offending_packagename>`, 
`conda update --all`
```

and then finally

```
`conda install <offending_packagename>`.
```

Answer (score 6):

To those of us who have miniconda and can't/don't want to install anaconda: the accepted answer works when adapted.

1. `conda install conda`
2. `conda update --all`

Would have commented, but my rep is too low.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem for ages. The `conda install anaconda` might work, but it takes just way too long -- more than 24 hours on my machine.

Here is a solution that worked for me in under 5 minutes:

1. Remove **all** the unneeded packages -- being careful to leave the ones that are essential for conda to operate.
2. Then, use `conda install anaconda`.

But how?? there is a lot of them!

This is what I have done:

1. Make a fresh envinroment with python, fairly bare-bone. then, list the packages in there:

`conda create -n fresh python`

`conda activate fresh`

`conda list`

Save the output, you will need it.
1b. go back to the base envinroment:

`conda deactivate`

2. use the following snippet to generate a `conda` command that will remove all the inconsistent packages:

(good packages are)

```py
exclusion_text = '''
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       1_gnu  
anyio                     2.2.0            py39h06a4308_1  
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py39h27cfd23_1  
async_generator           1.10               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
...
```

... and more! get this from a good environment.

Note the usage of triple quotes (''') to use a multiline-string in python.

```sh
bad_packages_text = '''
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64/networkx-2.1-py36_0.tar.bz2/linux-64::networkx==2.1=py36_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64/spyder-3.2.6-> py36_0.tar.bz2/linux-64::spyder==3.2.6=py36_0
py36h4c697fb_0.tar.bz2/linux-64::jdcal==1.3=py36h4c697fb_0
 - defaults/noarch::jupyterlab_server==1.1.4=py_0
 - defaults/linux-64::argh==0.26.2=py37_0
...
```

... and more! get this by copy-pasting the "The following packages are causing the inconsistency." message.

then, in python, process this:

```py
exclusions = [line.split(' ')[0] for line in exclusion_text_lines if line !='']
bad_packages_lines = bad_packages_text.split('\n')
bad_packages = [line.split('::')[1].split('==')[0] for line in bad_packages_lines if line!='']
exclusions.append('conda') # make sure!
exclusions.append('tqdm')
```

finally, construct the life-saving command:

```py
command_line = 'conda remove '
for bad_package in bad_packages:
    if bad_package not in exclusions:
        command_line = f'{command_line} {bad_package}'
command_line
```

Since in solving the environment, all the packages on the `remove` list can be ignored, `conda` no longer needs to consider their versions, and the process is fast.

Possibly someone can refactor this method to make it easier -- or better yet, upgrade `conda` to enable quick `reset base` command.

This worked for me -- it took me longer to write this post than to execute these actions.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

To solve this message I had to run `conda update --all` in my `base` environment *three* times after each other.
Every time the number of inconsistent packages decreased until `conda` said:

> # All requested packages already installed.

I'm on macOS Big Sur 11.6 using `conda` version `4.10.3`.

Comment: This worked for me and I'm on macOS BigSur 11.6 as well, I guess it's related to this operating system. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, none of the above worked. But this did the trick in less than a minute:

1- I downloaded again the lastest installer (miniconda in my case)

2- Run the installer with the -u option:

```
bash Miniconda3-py39_xxxx-Linux-x86_64.sh -u
```

3- Answer yes to all questions and let the installer finish

4- Then I could run conda update conda -all

Hope this helps...

Comment: This is what solved it for me, thanks!

Comment: Solved it for me using: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/

Answer (score 2):

```
conda install anaconda
conda clean --all
conda update --all
```

fix the problem for me

Answer (score 2):

Works with [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) + [Windows x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10) + [Python 3.10](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3100/):

```
conda activate base
conda update conda
conda update --all
```

Tested, works perfectly.

Note: Updating `base` is sufficient to fix issues with all other environments visible with `conda env list`.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me on my MacOS Ventura when I had to uninstall the osx-64 version and install the intel version (no comments from the peanut gallery, please). I got this when trying to "conda update conda":

```
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/osx-64::holoviews==1.15.0=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/noarch::babel==2.9.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/osx-64::anaconda-project==0.11.1=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::jupyterlab==3.4.4=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::datashader==0.14.1=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::anaconda==2022.10=py39_0
  - defaults/osx-64::hvplot==0.8.0=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::bkcharts==0.2=py39hecd8cb5_1
  - defaults/osx-64::conda-build==3.22.0=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::anaconda-navigator==2.4.0=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::sphinx==5.0.2=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf==0.1.0=py39hecd8cb5_1
  - defaults/osx-64::statsmodels==0.13.2=py39hca72f7f_0
  - defaults/osx-64::dask==2022.7.0=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::anaconda-client==1.11.0=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/noarch::jupyterlab_server==2.10.3=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/osx-64::numpydoc==1.4.0=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/noarch::intake==0.6.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/osx-64::pandas==1.4.4=py39he9d5cce_0
  - defaults/osx-64::jupyter==1.0.0=py39hecd8cb5_8
  - defaults/osx-64::conda-repo-cli==1.0.20=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/noarch::seaborn==0.11.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/osx-64::spyder==5.3.3=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/noarch::xarray==0.20.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1
```

I edited the output into this command and ran it:

```
conda uninstall holoviews babel anaconda-project jupyterlab datashader anaconda hvplot bkcharts conda-build anaconda-navigator sphinx _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf statsmodels dask anaconda-client jupyterlab_server numpydoc intake pandas jupyter conda-repo-cli seaborn spyder xarray
```

I then re-edited the command to this and ran it:

```
conda install holoviews babel anaconda-project jupyterlab datashader anaconda hvplot bkcharts conda-build anaconda-navigator sphinx _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf statsmodels dask anaconda-client jupyterlab_server numpydoc intake pandas jupyter conda-repo-cli seaborn spyder xarray
```

I did one final

```
conda update conda
```

and things appear to be well. (Note: make sure you answer "y" to any "Proceed ([y]/n)?" prompts.

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed anaconda with python 2.7 but later you used python 3.x. Thus, you are getting an error message. In my case, I solved the problem by activating anaconda with python 2.7:

```
conda create --name py2 python=2.7
```

Comment: Is there a way to determine which python version was used to install conda?

Answer (score 1):

In my environment.

1.

```bash
conda install anaconda
```

2. 

```bash
conda update --all
```

Then it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

My local environment is ubuntu 22.04
Tried to run:
`conda update anconda` it did not work.
what worked is removing the inconsistent package.
Below is the command to be run on terminal;

```
conda remove [inconsistent package name]
conda update --all
```

Answer (score 1):

Update at nov 23, 2023
Working on MacBook Pro, Apple M1 Pro, RAM 32 GB, macOS Sonoma Versión 14.0

It's incredible this problem persist after 4 years (as I can see in this post)

After trying all the solutions proposed here from the beginning the first one to return a slightly different output was https://stackoverflow.com/users/732596/jack-kelly from last year.

After running:

```
conda install conda --force-reinstall
```

I got

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \ 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:
```

and an almost infinite list of packages (I won't paste it because it's really huge), and at the end of the list the following message:

```
unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: / 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:
```

and again the huge list of packages.

And after that here it comes the difference:

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.7.4
  latest version: 23.10.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=23.10.0
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  setuptools         pkgs/main/osx-64::setuptools-68.0.0-py39hecd8cb5_0 
  wheel              pkgs/main/noarch::wheel-0.35.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0 


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
```

I aborted and retried

```
conda install conda --force-reinstall
```

And a new difference:

```
## Package Plan ##
```

```
added / updated specs:
    - conda


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    certifi-2023.11.17         |   py39hecd8cb5_0         159 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         159 KB

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  certifi                          2023.7.22-py39hecd8cb5_0 --> 2023.11.17-py39hecd8cb5_0 


Proceed ([y]/n)? y
```

And at last the list of packages will be downloaded:

```
package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    anaconda-anon-usage-0.4.3  | py39hfb7c958_100          25 KB
    anaconda-client-1.12.2     |   py39hecd8cb5_0         151 KB
    anaconda-cloud-auth-0.1.4  |   py39hecd8cb5_0          31 KB
    astropy-5.3.4              |   py39h7b7cdfe_0         8.2 MB
    async-lru-2.0.4            |   py39hecd8cb5_0          19 KB
    blinker-1.6.2              |   py39hecd8cb5_0          30 KB
    bokeh-3.3.0                |   py39h20db666_0         5.5 MB
    brotli-python-1.0.9        |   py39he9d5cce_7         354 KB
    cffi-1.16.0                |   py39h6c40b1e_0         240 KB
    click-8.1.7                |   py39hecd8cb5_0         164 KB
    .................. many more. ............
```

Then:

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  async-lru          pkgs/main/osx-64::async-lru-2.0.4-py39hecd8cb5_0 
  brotli-python      pkgs/main/osx-64::brotli-python-1.0.9-py39he9d5cce_7 
  jsonschema-specif~ pkgs/main/osx-64::jsonschema-specifications-2023.7.1-py39hecd8cb5_0 
  jupyter-lsp        pkgs/main/osx-64::jupyter-lsp-2.2.0-py39hecd8cb5_0 
  jupyter_server_te~ pkgs/main/osx-64::jupyter_server_terminals-0.4.4-py39hecd8cb5_1 
  overrides          pkgs/main/osx-64::overrides-7.4.0-py39hecd8cb5_0 
  referencing        pkgs/main/osx-64::referencing-0.30.2-py39hecd8cb5_0 
  rich               pkgs/main/osx-64::rich-13.3.5-py39hecd8cb5_0 
  rpds-py            pkgs/main/osx-64::rpds-py-0.10.6-py39hf2ad997_0 
  semver             pkgs/main/noarch::semver-2.13.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
```

After that:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:

  aiofiles-22.1.0-py39hecd8cb5_0
  aiosqlite-0.18.0-py39hecd8cb5_0
  brotlipy-0.7.0-py39h9ed2024_1003
  datashape-0.5.4-py39hecd8cb5_1
  jinja2-time-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_3
  jupyter_server_fileid-0.9.0-py39hecd8cb5_0
  jupyter_server_ydoc-0.8.0-py39hecd8cb5_1
  jupyter_ydoc-0.2.4-py39hecd8cb5_0
  nbclassic-0.5.5-py39hecd8cb5_0
  poyo-0.5.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pyrsistent-0.18.0-py39hca72f7f_0
  qtwebkit-5.212-hbfab81c_5
  y-py-0.5.9-py39h7242b5c_0
  ypy-websocket-0.8.2-py39hecd8cb5_0
```

and finally:

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

  anaconda-anon-usa~                   0.4.2-py39hfb7c958_2 --> 0.4.3-py39hfb7c958_100 
  anaconda-client                     1.12.1-py39hecd8cb5_0 --> 1.12.2-py39hecd8cb5_0 
  anaconda-cloud-au~                   0.1.3-py39hecd8cb5_0 --> 0.1.4-py39hecd8cb5_0 
  astropy                                5.1-py39h67323c0_0 --> 5.3.4-py39h7b7cdfe_0 
  blinker                                1.4-py39hecd8cb5_0 --> 1.6.2-py39hecd8cb5_0 
  bokeh                                3.2.1-py39h20db666_0 --> 3.3.0-py39h20db666_0 
  c-blosc2                                 2.8.0-hcec6c5f_0 --> 2.10.5-hcf5af9b_0 
  cffi                                1.15.1-py39h6c40b1e_3 --> 1.16.0-py39h6c40b1e_0 
  click                                8.0.4-py39hecd8cb5_0 --> 8.1.7-py39hecd8cb5_0 
  contourpy                            1.0.5-py39haf03e11_0 --> 1.2.0-py39ha357a0b_0 
  cookiecutter       pkgs/main/noarch::cookiecutter-1.7.3-~ --> pkgs/main/osx-64::cookiecutter-2.5.0-py39hecd8cb5_0 
  dal                               2023.1.1-ha357a0b_48680 --> 2023.1.1-ha357a0b_48681 
  datashader                          0.15.2-py39hecd8cb5_0 --> 0.16.0-py39hecd8cb5_0 
  filelock                             3.9.0-py39hecd8cb5_0 --> 3.13.1-py39hecd8cb5_0 
  frozenlist                           1.3.3-py39h6c40b1e_0 --> 1.4.0-py39h6c40b1e_0 
............   many more.  ............
```

and at the end

```
Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
                                                                                                                             
Preparing transaction: done                                                                                                  
Verifying transaction: done                                                                                                  
Executing transaction: done
```

I have to apologize for the length of the answer , but I think it can be useful for Mac users, who have little help here.

Answer (score -1):

Try to have a look to the environment management
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

By using something along the lines

```
conda create --name astra python=3.5
conda activate astra
conda install -c astra-toolbox astra-toolbox
```

You can see that you can even specify target python version. Now play with the new packages installed. When unsatisfied, you can always do

```
conda deactivate
conda env remove -n astra
```

If you install everything to the base env and something gets broken, then probably better is not to install conda at all and go with default python managing it through pip.