# Why does writing a dataframe to a file and reading it back again change the behavior of array assignment?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My task involves appending two dataframes of the same kind (representing different time periods) and applying a lambda function to modify a column on the appended dataframe.

This works as expected when run normally, but fails if the appended dataframe is written to csv and read back again.

Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir('/path//to/directory')

df = pd.read_csv('Data-May.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Data-TillApr.csv')

def foo(item):
    return item.replace("0"*11,"")
```

Applying lambda function individually on each dataframe - works

```
df['material'] = df.apply(lambda x: foo(x['material']), axis=1) #Works
df2['material'] = df2.apply(lambda x: foo(x['material']), axis=1) #Works
```

Applying lambda function on the appended dataframe - works

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data-May.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Data-TillApr.csv')
df3 = df2.append(df) 
df3['material'] = df3.apply(lambda x: foo(x['material']), axis=1) #Works
```

Applying lambda function on the dataframe df3 if saved and read back  - fails

It works if a new column is created though.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data-May.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Data-TillApr.csv')
df3 = df2.append(df)
df3.to_csv('Data-Appended.csv') #Writing to csv
df4 = pd.read_csv('Data-Appended.csv') #Reading it into a dataframe


df4['material'] = df4.apply(lambda x: foo(x['material']), axis=1) #Doesn't work

df4['new'] = df4.apply(lambda x: foo(x['material']), axis=1) #Works
```

The dtype for df3['material'] and df4['material'] are of type o.

Traceback output for the line that doesn't work:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "<ipython-input-42-096f7e61633e>", line 1, in <module>
>     df4['material'] = df4.apply(lambda x: foo(x['material']), axis=1) #Doesn't work
>
>   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
> ```
>
> line 2331, in **setitem**
>           self._set_item(key, value)
>
> ```
>   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
> ```
>
> line 2398, in _set_item
>           NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
>
> ```
>   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py",
> ```
>
> line 1759, in _set_item
>           self._data.set(key, value)
>
> ```
>   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py",
> ```
>
> line 3731, in set
>           group=True):
>
> ```
>   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py",
> ```
>
> line 4684, in _get_blkno_placements
>           for blkno, indexer in lib.get_blkno_indexers(blknos, group):
>
> ```
>   File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 1488, in pandas._libs.lib.get_blkno_indexers
>
> ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)
> ```

Comment: please supply some data rows so we could help understand better your question, also, consider using dtype when reading the csv to decide on column data type @Hemanth G

Comment: Hi @masasa, thanks for replying. I am unable to share rows at the moment, dtype for both df3 & df4 were identical and the error remained when I used 'str' to read the offending column.

Comment: ill wait , a few (fake data if needed) data to replicte the problem is extremely important , more over in pandas..

Comment: Hi, I am unable to replicate the error elsewhere. On the original machine, I encountered an "environment is inconsistent" error similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527354/the-environment-is-inconsistent-please-check-the-package-plan-carefully , the original error did not recur after I reinstalled anaconda. All is well for now, I hope I don't see it again.