# The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully - cvxopt

Tags: python, machine-learning, terminal, anaconda, cvxopt

I have tried to install cvxopt for macOS Sierra 10.12.6 .

Than I have tried to solve this problem by all the tips of [The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527354/the-environment-is-inconsistent-please-check-the-package-plan-carefully) but non of them worked and gave similar error messages like the one bellow.

I have tried:

- `conda clean --all`   [and then]  `conda update --all`
- `conda update --all` [only]
- `conda install`
- `conda install anaconda`
- one by one installing the problematic packages

Main ERROR message after `conda install -c anaconda cvxopt`

```
MyMachine:~ me$ conda install -c anaconda cvxopt 
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - omnia/osx-64::autograd==1.1.2=np112py36_0
failed
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - omnia/osx-64::autograd==1.1.2=np112py36_0
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

  - anaconda/osx-64::pandas==0.24.2=py36h0a44026_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.12.1,<2.0a0']
  - anaconda/osx-64::quandl==3.4.5=py36_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.8']
  - autograd -> numpy=1.12
  - conda-forge/noarch::torchfile==0.1.0=py_0 -> numpy
  - conda-forge/noarch::visdom==0.1.8.5=0 -> numpy
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::blaze==0.10.1=py36_0 -> dask -> bokeh[version='>=1.0.0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.7.1']
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::blaze==0.10.1=py36_0 -> pytables[version='>=3.0.0'] -> numexpr
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::datashape==0.5.4=py36_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.7']
  - pkgs/free/osx-64::odo==0.5.0=py36_1 -> datashape[version='>=0.5'] -> numpy[version='>=1.7']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::anaconda==2019.03=py36_0 -> bokeh==1.0.4=py36_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.7.1']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::anaconda==2019.03=py36_0 -> cython==0.29.6=py36h0a44026_0
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::anaconda==2019.03=py36_0 -> gevent==1.4.0=py36h1de35cc_0
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::anaconda==2019.03=py36_0 -> importlib_metadata==0.8=py36_0
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::anaconda==2019.03=py36_0 -> mkl-service==1.1.2=py36hfbe908c_5
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::anaconda==2019.03=py36_0 -> numexpr==2.6.9=py36h7413580_0
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::anaconda==2019.03=py36_0 -> ply==3.11=py36_0
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::anaconda==2019.03=py36_0 -> scikit-learn==0.20.3=py36h27c97d8_0
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::anaconda==2019.03=py36_0 -> zipp==0.3.3=py36_1
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::astropy==3.1.2=py36h1de35cc_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.13.3,<2.0a0']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::bkcharts==0.2=py36h073222e_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.7.1']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::bokeh==1.0.4=py36_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.7.1']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::bottleneck==1.2.1=py36h1d22016_1 -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::cython==0.29.6=py36h0a44026_0
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::dask==1.1.4=py36_1 -> bokeh[version='>=0.13.0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.7.1']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::gevent==1.4.0=py36h1de35cc_0
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::h5py==2.9.0=py36h3134771_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::imageio==2.5.0=py36_0 -> numpy
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::importlib_metadata==0.8=py36_0 -> zipp[version='>=0.3.2']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::matplotlib==3.0.3=py36h54f8f79_0 -> numpy
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::mkl-service==1.1.2=py36hfbe908c_5
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::mkl_fft==1.0.10=py36h5e564d8_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::numba==0.43.1=py36h6440ff4_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::numexpr==2.6.9=py36h7413580_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.15.4,<2.0a0']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::numpy-base==1.16.2=py36h6575580_0 -> numpy==1.16.2=py36hacdab7b_0
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::numpy==1.16.2=py36hacdab7b_0
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::path.py==11.5.0=py36_0 -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.5']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::patsy==0.5.1=py36_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.4.0']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::ply==3.11=py36_0
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::pytables==3.5.1=py36h5bccee9_0 -> numexpr -> numpy[version='>=1.15.4,<2.0a0']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::pytest-arraydiff==0.3=py36h39e3cac_0 -> numpy
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::pytest-astropy==0.5.0=py36_0 -> pytest-arraydiff[version='>=0.1'] -> numpy
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::pytest-doctestplus==0.3.0=py36_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.10']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::pywavelets==1.0.2=py36h1d22016_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::scikit-image==0.14.2=py36h0a44026_0 -> imageio[version='>=2.1.0'] -> numpy
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::scikit-learn==0.20.3=py36h27c97d8_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::scipy==1.2.1=py36h1410ff5_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::seaborn==0.9.0=py36_0 -> matplotlib[version='>=1.4.3'] -> numpy
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::statsmodels==0.9.0=py36h1d22016_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0']
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::zipp==0.3.3=py36_1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. just uninstall anaconda https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/ with all it's packages than reinstall.
2. if that did not work than reinstall all other package management tool.: homebrew, miniconda, pip and anaconda.

Comment: That sounds very broken. Time to switch to another package manager