# "The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully"

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda

I would have a follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890335/the-environment-is-inconsistent-please-check-the-package-plan-carefully-cvxop). The accepted answer states that the solution to the error message

> The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
> The following packages are causing the inconsistency: [...]

is to type `conda install anaconda`. Where exactly am I supposed to do this?

**My problem is that when I go into my environment and type this command, then I still get the above mentioned error messsage, so I'm not sure what to do..**