# Conda error: The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully

Tags: python, windows-10, anaconda, command-prompt, conda

I tried to update my Pandas package via Conda prompt, however, it altered me the 'environment inconsistency'

I have tried 'conda install anaconda' from the advice: [The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527354/the-environment-is-inconsistent-please-check-the-package-plan-carefully)

But it does not fix the problem, it failed

(base) C:\Users\leon>conda install anaconda

Collecting package metadata: done

Solving environment: \

The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully

The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

- conda-forge/noarch::altair==2.1.0=py_0
- defaults/win-64::anaconda==custom=py36h363777c_0
- defaults/win-64::anaconda-navigator==1.9.7=py36_0
- defaults/win-64::astropy==2.0.2=py36h06391c4_4
- defaults/win-64::bkcharts==0.2=py36h7e685f7_0
- defaults/win-64::blaze==0.11.3=py36h8a29ca5_0
- defaults/win-64::bokeh==1.0.1=py36_0
- defaults/win-64::bottleneck==1.2.1=py36hd119dfa_0
- conda-forge/win-64::catboost==0.8.1=py36_0
- defaults/win-64::dask==0.20.2=py36_0
- defaults/win-64::datashape==0.5.4=py36h5770b85_0
- conda-forge/noarch::folium==0.5.0=py_0
- defaults/win-64::h5py==2.7.0=py36hfbe0a52_1
- defaults/win-64::imageio==2.2.0=py36had6c2d2_0
- conda-forge/win-64::keras==2.2.4=py36_0
- conda-forge/noarch::keras-applications==1.0.4=py_1
- conda-forge/noarch::keras-preprocessing==1.0.2=py_1
- conda-forge/win-64::lightgbm==2.1.0=py36_0
- defaults/win-64::matplotlib==2.1.0=py36h11b4b9c_0
- conda-forge/noarch::mlxtend==0.13.0=py_1
- defaults/win-64::mro-basics==3.4.3=0
- defaults/win-64::numba==0.35.0=np113py36_10
- defaults/win-64::numexpr==2.6.2=py36h7ca04dc_1
- defaults/win-64::odo==0.5.1=py36h7560279_0
- conda-forge/win-64::opencv==3.4.1=py36_200
- defaults/win-64::pandas==0.23.4=py36h830ac7b_0
- defaults/win-64::patsy==0.4.1=py36h42cefec_0
- defaults/win-64::py-xgboost==0.7=py36h6538335_0
- conda-forge/win-64::pyedflib==0.1.13=py36h452e1ab_1
- conda-forge/win-64::pygpu==0.7.6=py36_0
- defaults/win-64::pytables==3.4.2=py36h71138e3_2
- pytorch/win-64::pytorch==1.1.0=py3.6_cuda100_cudnn7_1
- defaults/win-64::pywavelets==0.5.2=py36hc649158_0
- defaults/win-64::r-essentials==3.4.3=mro343_0
- defaults/win-64::r-png==0.1_7=r3.1.3_0a
- defaults/win-64::r-recommended==3.4.3=mro343_0
- defaults/win-64::rstudio==1.1.423=h8c352d3_0
- defaults/win-64::scikit-image==0.13.0=py36h6dffa3f_1
- defaults/win-64::scikit-learn==0.19.1=py36h53aea1b_0
- defaults/win-64::seaborn==0.8.0=py36h62cb67c_0
- conda-forge/win-64::shapely==1.6.2=py36_0
- defaults/win-64::statsmodels==0.8.0=py36h6189b4c_0
- conda-forge/win-64::tensorboard==1.8.0=py36_1
- conda-forge/win-64::tensorflow==1.8.0=py36_1
- conda-forge/win-64::theano==1.0.2=py36_0
- pytorch/noarch::torchvision==0.2.2=py_3
- conda-forge/noarch::vincent==0.4.4=py_1

failed

Comment: Did you try the other advice on that page, `conda update --all`?