# The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully - openblas

Tags: conda, conflict, openblas

I tried to update or install new packages from anaconda and lately, this message has appeared:

```
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - conda-forge/linux-64::liblapacke==3.8.0=12_openblas
  - conda-forge/linux-64::libblas==3.8.0=12_openblas
  - conda-forge/linux-64::libwebp==1.0.2=h576950b_1
  - conda-forge/linux-64::liblapack==3.8.0=12_openblas
  - conda-forge/linux-64::libcblas==3.8.0=12_openblas
```

done
I tried with conda clean --all and then conda update --all but it persists.

conda info

```
active environment : None
        shell level : 0
   user config file : /home/gupy/.condarc
populated config files : 
      conda version : 4.7.11
conda-build version : 3.17.8
     python version : 3.7.3.final.0
   virtual packages : 
   base environment : /home/gupy/anaconda3  (writable)
       channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
      package cache : /home/gupy/anaconda3/pkgs
                      /home/gupy/.conda/pkgs
   envs directories : /home/gupy/anaconda3/envs
                      /home/gupy/.conda/envs
           platform : linux-64
         user-agent : conda/4.7.11 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.3 Linux/4.15.0-58-generic ubuntu/18.04.3 glibc/2.27
            UID:GID : 1000:1000
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for creating this question.
I know it's a bit late to drop late to answer, however, if you finally had a workaround, it may help someone to know how I was able to solve mine. Enough apology...

The error message indicates inconsistency with core anaconda libraries. For me, this all started when my laptop suddenly turned off in the cause of a package installation.

You can solve this in the following steps:
1

1. Install each of those packages.
   Start by installing **liblapacks**. You'll find all available packages on [Conda Forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge) (e.g. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/liblapack).

> Note: After installing package one, it added others. Then I was able to go to step 2.

2. Run the following command from the command line: `conda update --all`.

> If you've any issues with step 2, you may want to look at this
>   StackOverflow question:
>   [The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527354/the-environment-is-inconsistent-please-check-the-package-plan-carefully)