# Package Inconsistencies and Permission Denied Error For All Of My Installs

Tags: python, macos, installation, conda

Lately, every time I try to install a package using conda I am getting message saying `The following packages are causing the inconsistency` and then this error:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(696): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::numpy-base-1.16.4-py37ha711998_0'.

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/<myusername>/anaconda3/envs/dsi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/LICENSE.txt'
```

I tried searching around and I cannot find a good answer to my problem.

Thank you in advance for all of your help.

Comment: what's your install command?

Comment: I am using conda and pip.

Comment: but whats the command?

Comment: conda install <package> or pip install <package>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527354/the-environment-is-inconsistent-please-check-the-package-plan-carefully)

Comment: I have read that post before.  The problem is that none of the step in that post worked.

Comment: `pip install --user <package>`