# Anaconda failure to "solve environment" repeatedly

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I want to update my python version. When running

```
conda update python
```

from my base environment I get the message:

> The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
> and then I get a message about trying to solve using flexible solve, where the terminal just runs without completing.

I have tried everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527354/the-environment-is-inconsistent-please-check-the-package-plan-carefully) and [here](https:////https://exerror.com/solving-environment-failed-with-initial-frozen-solve-retrying-with-flexible-solve/) and all lead to my terminal freezing on the same message.

I have also tried to uninstall conda but the clean command [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) also leads to freezing.

How can I completely uninstall conda and remove all packages/dependencies and reinstall a new version?

Comment: You on a mac? I recently completely removed anaconda from my mac using the instructions [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/), although I noticed there are Windows instructions too. It was a bit scary with the removing of directories, but it got rid of anaconda (and solved my Streamlit running problems eventually).

Comment: Yes on a mac. I tried these same steps and my terminal was hanging on the clean command. For now I installed a virtual environment, until I can figure out how to fix the base conda env.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to use navigate to Users/name/opt/ and run

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda3
```

which removed the base environment and all scripts related to anaconda and to reinstall using the GUI [here](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution#macos) for the version of python I needed.

This is the only thing that fixed my problem. Likely there are many packages that I will now need to reinstall...