# how can I solve conda inconsistent error?

Tags: python, conda

I tried to download tensorflow with anaconda, and

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: | 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/osx-64::_anaconda_depends==2022.05=py39_0
  - defaults/osx-64::scrapy==2.6.2=py39hecd8cb5_0
  - defaults/osx-64::bcrypt==3.2.0=py39hca72f7f_1
  - defaults/osx-64::twisted==22.2.0=py39hca72f7f_1
  - defaults/osx-64::anaconda==custom=py39_1
```

this showed up. Should I delete all off these files? If I should, how can I remove it?

I tried to update or clean conda, but it didn't work because it stucks at the solving environment.

-failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /

or

-Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: /

**so, right now 'conda install'is not working for me.**

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527354/the-environment-is-inconsistent-please-check-the-package-plan-carefully