# Conda not updating itself

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, auto-update

I'm trying to update Anaconda because of an issue that showed up when installing some new packages ([The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527354/the-environment-is-inconsistent-please-check-the-package-plan-carefully)). When I tried to follow the main advice here and running `conda update -all` I got the following message

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
current version: 22.9.0
latest version: 23.11.0

Please update conda by running
$ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

I ran the update anyway, which ended up solving my initial issue, but now if I try to update conda, with either the provided line `conda update -n base -c defaults conda` or with just `conda update conda`, conda gets stuck in a loop where it keeps updating/downgrading my anaconda packages as if i'm updating --all, but when i check the conda version (`conda --version`) it's still on version 22.9.

I also tried running `counda clean -all` which some comments on the mentioned posted said can help in some cases when `conda update` is acting up, but so far it's still stuck like this. I was trying to avoid reinstalling Anaconda altogether so I was wondering if anyone else has gotten stuck in this step.

Comment: Yes! I figured it's all saved to my C:\Users folder so I will just be doing a physical backup of the files and copying them someplace else for safety if reinstallation does turn out to be the only option, thank you