# Conda environment inability to update

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

The title itself is pretty clear, but I used conda update function (on spyder, and on the conda console). I just did the software update.
As you can see I have some package causing inconsistency.
What would you do ?

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

# All requested packages already installed.


Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/win-64::anaconda-client==1.7.2=py38_0
  - defaults/win-64::anaconda-cloud-auth==0.1.4=py38haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::anaconda==custom=py38_2
  - defaults/win-64::anaconda-navigator==2.5.2=py38haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::anaconda-project==0.9.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/noarch::conda-repo-cli==1.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::importlib_metadata==3.10.0=hd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::ipykernel==5.3.4=py38h5ca1d4c_0
  - defaults/noarch::ipywidgets==7.6.3=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/noarch::jsonschema==3.2.0=py_2
  - defaults/win-64::jupyter==1.0.0=py38_7
  - defaults/noarch::jupyterlab==3.0.14=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/noarch::jupyterlab_server==2.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::jupyter_client==8.6.0=py38haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::jupyter_console==6.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::jupyter_server==1.4.1=py38haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::keyring==23.13.1=py38haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::nbclassic==0.2.6=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::nbclient==0.5.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::nbconvert==6.0.7=py38_0
  - defaults/noarch::nbformat==5.1.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::notebook==6.3.0=py38haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::numba==0.58.1=py38hd77b12b_0
  - defaults/noarch::qtconsole==5.0.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::spyder==4.2.5=py38haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::spyder-kernels==1.10.2=py38haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::widgetsnbextension==3.5.1=py38_0
  - defaults/win-64::_anaconda_depends==2020.07=py38_0
  - defaults/win-64::_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf==0.1.0=py38_0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527354/the-environment-is-inconsistent-please-check-the-package-plan-carefully)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found The answer. In anaconda you have environments, with libraries. I was working on an environment which had libraries incompatible with newer versions so I could not update it. My solution was then create a new environment and only use libraries that works with later versions of python/conda.