# I deleted the Anaconda, but it remains in the Start menu

Tags: anaconda, startmenu

I deleted `anaconda`, but it remains in the Windows Start menu. How do I remove anaconda from the Start menu?

There is no anaconda in `"C: \ ProgramData \ Microsoft \ Windows \ Start Menu \ Programs"` However, it still appears in the Start menu.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/3462

Comment: May or may not be a possible duplicate of [How to remove anaconda from windows completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29337928/11683)

Answer (score 0):

While running Windows 10 Pro, I recently had the same issue after uninstalling Anaconda3 with Anaconda's uninstaller.

Try deleting the Anaconda3 folder from the following directory to remove the related shortcuts.
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"

Note: This fix assumes Anaconda3 was previously installed using default directories.

Answer (score 0):

just click on the white blank file icon. it will ask if you want to delete it. say yes. i am sure you fixed it by now.

Answer (score 0):

delete the files of Anaconda from this location

C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).