# Anaconda Navigator not launching(via anaconda prompt) after displaying logo (in windows 10)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

[screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqW6Q.png)

I've also tried things like:

```
1. conda update --all
2. conda uninstall anaconda
3. conda install anaconda
4. conda update anaconda-navigator
5. anaconda-navigator --reset
6. deleted .condarc file from the main directory
7. conda install pyqt5
8. conda install pyqtwebengine
```

but none of them worked

anaconda version 2020.2
python version 3.7.6

Comment: You don't believe, but after updating Spyder to 4.__ I faced a similar situation. I had to reboot my windows for that, after all, the uninstallations and installations. this might not be a helpful comment but that's what worked and never went for updates again. (Noob things)

Comment: This link and the answer might be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53271833/12085569

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me:

1. Uninstall Anaconda
2. Delete all files/folders for _conda and Anaconda under (i) C:\Users\xxx\  (ii) C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local (iii) C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming
3. Reinstall Anaconda
4. Go to C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\Scripts and execute anaconda-navigator.exe