# Need help creating a fresh install of anaconda due to error starting kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Essentially, for the past few days Jupyter has displayed an error concerning the kernel, in the fashion of "Error Starting Kernel - Unhandled error". At times, it displayed the message "TypeError: KernelManager.update_env() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" along with it, but that seems to have disappeared.

Thus far I have attempted to:

- Uninstall anaconda, delete the jupyter folder from AppData and reinstall
- Pip update jupyter lab, notebook and server
- Pip reinstall traitlets
- Add Anaconda and Python's location to the system path
- jupyter kernelspec remove python3 and reinstall

The same error keeps popping up. I feel like at this point, I might as well create a fresh install, but I have no idea how to achieve any further than what I have done in step 1. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I feel like there is a lot on here and other places about step #1, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62979247/8508004).  Anaconda should handle adding itself to the path once you uninstall **completely** and reinstall. You shouldn't have to deal with `pip` if you are using Anaconda.. You'll only use it in Anaconda/conda for packages with no recipe. You'd need to specify better what is happening that disagrees with those sources. You don't even say what type of a system you are using? I'm guess a Mac given mention of 'AppData' but we shouldn't have to struggle to get what you seek. ...

Comment: Importantly, Mac's have Python in the system you don't want to mess with. (I thought they made it harder to mess with this in the last few Mac OSs as historically users would mess it up.) I have a lot of advice about Mac's and Jupyter/Python assembled [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-solve-no-jupyter-binary-and-only-dashed-version-jupyter-lab-binary/23388/2?u=fomightez). You may benefit digging into some of that if you aren't going to go with Anaconda again.