# How to remove python from windows which is not found in program files of control panel

Tags: python, python-install

I had python version 3.8.2 installed but it was version 32bit so I uninstalled it but after uninstalling when I type ***python --version*** in cmd it showed like this,

[image]

Then I used Anaconda prompt and typed ***python*** it showed like this,

[image]

So I'm a bit confused and I want to remove all the python versions so I can install the new version without any issues.
And in the program files in control panel there is no Python 3.7.4 displayed.
And I checked in the environmental variables and there is no variable related to python.
And if I enter only ***python*** in the command prompt then it opens Microsoft store.

So I have no way of uninstalling this. How to fix this ?

Comment: You had two separate python installations - the one you did manually (3.8.2) and one done by Anaconda. Generally, the Anaconda's one should not interfere with your manual installation, so you probably don't need to worry about it (you may want to upgrade python in it, though). You say you have "checked your environmental variables" - did it include checking entries in your Path variables (both user and system)?

Answer (score 10):

I think you had two python installations. Try these commands for uninstall python:

```
cd C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
del python.exe
del python3.exe
```

And uninstall Anaconda this way: [How to remove anaconda from windows completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337928/how-to-remove-anaconda-from-windows-completely)