# Anaconda uninstaller does not uninstall anything

Tags: windows, anaconda, conda, uninstallation

I've been trying to uninstall Anaconda and reinstall it.
I tried every possible solution (listed here: [How to remove anaconda from windows completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337928/how-to-remove-anaconda-from-windows-completely)) but it simply doesn't work.

The uninstaller runs and says "uninstall completed" but does not uninstall anything.

I've been trying both from control panel and from the Anaconda 3 folder, which contains an uninstaller.
After the completed uninstall, Anaconda is still present in my program list and all the folders are still there, nothing has been uninstalled.

I'm using a Windows 10 PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing the Anaconda3 folder by hand and then deleting the references to Anaconda in my start menu and control panel.

For some strange reason the uninstaller didn't do anything at all.