# remove or fix broken anaconda installation

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have a badly broken Anaconda installation. When I go to Windows Settings > Apps & Features and search Anaconda, I see this:

[image]

Attempting to uninstall gives me the following pop-up error:

```
Windows cannot find 'C:\Users\xianx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Uninstall-Anaconda3.exe'.
Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

[image]

I attempted to follow this YouTube video, using `regedit` to remove the installation, but I couldn't find anything with the name "anaconda" in the list.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StrCtt9B9kQ

Inside this regedit though, I did find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Python > Continuum` and I deleted that folder. It did not help.

Simply reinstalling Anaconda results in a new version:
[image]

Uninstalling the new version does nothing to fix the old corrupted version.

When I try to start Anaconda Prompt with the new version installed, I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xianx\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

When I try to verify the new installation, I get:

```
C:\Users\xianx>conda list
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried to follow some of the solutions here, but none of them work for me. My Anaconda Prompt does not seem to work properly, my `conda` command is broken, uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't work: ['Conda' is not recognized as internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515769/conda-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command)

```
C:\Users\xianx>where conda
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

How do I fix this mess?

Comment: Also found those answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54453907/7560466 and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58889740/7560466 both from here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29337928/7560466

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what to suggest to delete it properly but what can be tried:

 0)Delete the newer version (Delete all versions of Conda)

 1) look over C://Program Files and Program Files (x86)
for Anaconda, python and continium folder and check C://Anaconda3 and `C:\Users\xianx\AppData\Local\Continuum` check if this folder is still exists.

 2) Try to use Uninstaller app as RevoUninstaller or
IObit Uninstaller (apps can be deleted after helping deleting Conda) they search all folders and especially Registry.
3)Install new Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

My problem with the new installation was that I had multiple Python installations all over the place. Once I cleaned those out of my PATH environment variable and put in the Anaconda ones, the issue resolved itself.