# Failed in installing anaconda, there are only three folders after installation

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I installed the latest version of Anaconda last October, but this year when I wanted to use it I found that the anaconda navigator runs very slow and lags a lot. So I uninstalled it and wanted to reinstall it so as to see if this problem can be solved. However, when I began to reinstall it, a series of errors occurred. I have tried several versions of installation packages and all of them failed to install anaconda, reporting the “FileNotFoundError:[WinError 2] (the Chinese sentence here means “The system cannot find the file specified”)” Then I tried everything, including switching the installation position
to another disk, removing the.anaconda and.conda folders under C: \Users\Administer, and so on, but nothing worked. Finally, I found a version of Anaconda released at the end of 2017, version 3.5.0.0, and finally installed it properly. However, the python version is 3.6 in anaconda 3.5.0.0, and some packages I want to use do not work or cannot be installed. Besides, I ran into new problems when using the command “conda update anaconda” in Prompt. These included memory leaks and the mysterious disappearances of the two apps Anaconda Navigator and Anaconda Prompt. So I had to uninstall anaconda once again. Is there any way to successfully install the latest version of Anaconda and Python?

My installation process is as follows. My system is windows7(64bit).

[installation process 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZueCi.png)

[installation process 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40xwM.png)

[installation process 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1EWw.png)

[there are only three folders after installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zpro.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should completely uninstall Anaconda first before you give it a new try, see the official docs here: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

Then there is also another stackoverflow post that you might want to look at in case of further trouble: [How to remove anaconda from windows completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337928/how-to-remove-anaconda-from-windows-completely)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Though I finally decided to reinstall my windows 7 and then these problems I encountered just all disappeared…